# What's the best way to avoid chargebacks in an ecommerce web app?

Tags: web-applications, e-commerce, credit-card

Is there a particular payment method that is less susceptible to chargebacks than others?

Comment: @Stephen: I prefer indentured servitude, but I don't get many takers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best advice on this I've read:

#### [How we reduced chargebacks by 30%](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1545-how-we-reduced-chargebacks-by-30-as-a-percentage-of-sales):

> I decided to register 37signals-charge.com, redirect it to 37signals.com/charge, write up a page explaining why there’s a charge on your card, and put that URL on people’s charge slips instead of “37signals, LLC” or “Basecamp” or “Highrise” etc.
>
> Now when someone buys something from us, this line item shows up on their credit card statement:
>
> *37signals-charge.com 800.xxx.xxxx IL*
>
> Visiting that URL takes you to [this page](http://www.37signals.com/charge) where we explain the charge, the products, some suggestions if you don’t recognize the products, and a link to our billing support form someone needs additional help.

Summary:

- Sell something people will be happy with
- Provide a great purchasing experience from start to finish
- Make it easy to figure out where/how the charge came from later

Answer (score 2):

I use PayPal, and I think I've had maybe 2 chargebacks in the last 5 years.

I think the frequency of chargebacks is more dependent upon the quality of the products and services you offer than on the provider of the payment mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

provide a good product with better service. Dont leave customers hanging after the sale!
I don't see how changing a processor would help with chargeback. (maybe with fees associated with chargeback)